# How can I update a Tkinter widget inside a multiprocess?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, tk-toolkit

I am trying to update a frame using a process, but I am unable to do so. If I don’t use a process, the frame is updating with the child elements, but not when using multiprocess.

This is what I've tried (the code is part of a class):

```
def zx(self, q):
    print('asdadsas')
    lbl = Label(self.myframe, text="assagj")
    lbl.pack(ipady=2, padx=10, pady=5, anchor=NW)
```

```
try:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.zx, args=('a', ))
    p.daemon=True
    p.start()
    sleep(2)
    p.terminate()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p.terminate()
except:
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: save yourself the heartache, and switch to Qt now... the documentation is top notch, and it has a solution for just about everything (including both threads and processes communicating with the main event loop). The only slight problem is that the docs are for C++, but the python interface is identical 99.99% of the time.

Comment: @Aaron Tkinter can do just about anything and is well documented as well. In this situation I would use threading instead of multiprocess.

Comment: I hate C++ but love C for some reason and it is for my small project and python+tk is the quickest so i guess i am stuck with that for now.

Comment: @Mike i also tried with threading and got the same results, do you think there's any work-around?

Comment: @Mike-SMT `tkinter` isn't threadsafe so you shouldn't be using it from different threads. I have seen `tkinter` crash without an error traceback when accessing it from another thread.

Comment: @kup Can you please show us what exactly are you trying to do? Right now you can just call the function so I am assuming that there is something more to it. Most of the time you can just use `.after` to schedule your functions to be called in the future.

Comment: @TheLizzard Tkinter needs to be in the main thread but you can use a thread to work data or other external processes and simply pass a variable to the thread to update the variable.

Comment: @Mike-SMT The data that you work with (in the other thread) shouldn't access `tkinter` variables. I have seen bugs where just passing in a widget as a parameter to a new thread can raise issues. I will try to find the issue on the python bug tracker. It should still be there

Comment: @TheLizzard hum. Interesting. If that is the case then I will need to rebuild a lot of programs for my job :D

Comment: @Mike-SMT Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/N1d8Z62R). I just created it because I can't find the original bug report. On python 3.9 Win 10, tcl (the library that tkinter uses) causes the python interpreter to crash. This is why you shouldn't even pass in your tkinter widgets/variables in another thread.

Comment: @TheLizzard That appears to be passing root. I would never do that. I am passing things like a class atrubute for a list or dict.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I am just showing you that it isn't that hard to make python crash without an error traceback when using `tkinter` in threads other then where you created the `Tk()` window. The problem is that it doesn't give you a traceback so it's very hard to debug. I have ran into that problem before on a big project and my only option was to restart the whole project. That is why I advise people not to use `tkinter` and `threading` unless they really know the risks.

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter widgets can't span processes. All access to Tkinter widgets must be from within the same process.

This is because the widgets exist in an embedded [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) interpreter, and that Tcl interpreter can't be shared across processes.