# Use to infinite active proccess at the same time in python

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Hello I would like to use tkinter and lcu-driver to create a graphic application using both libraries but I cannot activate both at the same time.

I have tried with multiprocessing as it is shown and I have not reach any solution, It is only started the first instruction set.

```
def lol():
    connector.start()

def graph():
    raiz.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=lol) 
    p1.run()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=graph)
    p.run()
```

Do you have any idea about how to use both processes at the same time?

Comment: You can't use `multiprocessing` with `tkinter`. And you shouldn't use `threading` with `tkinter`. Try looking at `.after` scripts.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68412013/11106801) recent question.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying: tkinter functions should not be called outside the main thread, but doing other work in a thread is just fine.